# 550 5.7.1 Message Rejected due to content restrictions

Tags: email, exchange, smtp

I have a server that for some reason, out of the blue is now having a huge amount of its email being rejected, coming back with 550 5.7.1 NDR's or various derivatives thereof.  This just started happening a couple days ago suddenly. This is happening to a large number of domains.  At first I thought it was just email hosted by GoDaddy because several of them were hosted there.  However, it is now apparent that the issue is much more widespread.

I have:

- Checked DNSBL lists.
- Scanned the Local PC's for Malware/spyware.
- Verified that only the server can send SMTP traffic through the firewall.
- Sent email address through an administrator account.
- Sent emails that are only text based.
- Sent emails that are HTML based.
- Sent basic emails (nothing attached, just a test text body, no signature).
- Sent email through OWA directly.
- Had the recipients add the domain to a safe sender list in Outlook.
- Verified SPF records.
- Verified rDNS records.
- For the fun of it changed the external IP address that the email flows from with no change.

I am running out of ideas to try.  Any suggestions would be GREATLY appreciated.
This server is connected directly to the firewall, the firewall does not perform any filtering.

I am pasting an example NDR.  What is really odd is that it looks like it passes all the spam checks and is given a SPF rating of -4, mentions that is is on a safe sender and then just gives up.

```
#< #5.7.1 smtp;550 5.7.1 Message rejected due to content restrictions> #SMTP#

Original message headers:

Received: from mail23-am1-R.bigfish.com ([161.7.8.25]) by DOAISD75213.mtdmz.ad
 over TLS secured channel with Microsoft SMTPSVC(7.0.6002.18222);         Fri, 21 Feb
 2014 08:31:22 -0700
Received: from mail23-am1 (localhost [127.0.0.1])
        by mail23-am1-R.bigfish.com (Postfix) with ESMTP id ADCFD1003A1
        for <_________>; Fri, 21 Feb 2014 15:31:20 +0000 (UTC)
X-Forefront-Antispam-Report: CIP:69.146.164.109;KIP:(null);UIP:(null);IPV:NLI;H:mail.bearpaw.org;RD:mail.bearpaw.org;EFVD:NLI
X-SpamScore: -4
X-BigFish: vps-4(zz1861Ic89bh103dKa40Ic857hde40hzz1f42h2148h208ch1ee6h1de0h1fdah2073h2146h1202h1e76h2189h1d1ah1d2ah21bch1fc6hzz1de098h8275bh1de097h186068hz2fh109h2a8h839h8e2h8e3hd25h1288h12a5h12bdh137ah13eah1441h1504h1537h153bh15d0h162dh1631h1758h18e1h1946h19b5h1b0ah1bceh224fh1d0ch1d2eh1d3fh1dc1h1dfeh1dffh1e1dh1fe8h1ff5h20f0h2216h22d0h2336h2438h2461h2487h24d7h2516h2545h255ehbe9i34h1155h)
X-MS-Exchange-Organization-Force-TLS: 0
X-FFO-Routing-Override: mt.gov%161.7.8.28;
Received-SPF: pass (mail23-am1: domain of bearpaw.org designates 69.146.164.109 as permitted sender) client-ip=69.146.164.109; envelope-from=__________; helo=mail.bearpaw.org ;.bearpaw.org ;
X-MS-Exchange-Organization-Antispam-Report: OrigIP: 69.146.164.109;Service: EHS
Received: from mail23-am1 (localhost.localdomain [127.0.0.1]) by mail23-am1 (MessageSwitch) id 1392996678568717_17980; Fri, 21 Feb 2014 15:31:18 +0000 (UTC)
Received: from AM1EHSMHS006.bigfish.com (unknown [10.3.201.228])
        by mail23-am1.bigfish.com (Postfix) with ESMTP id 7ADCB240079
        for <_________>; Fri, 21 Feb 2014 15:31:18 +0000 (UTC)
Received: from mail.bearpaw.org (69.146.164.109) by AM1EHSMHS006.bigfish.com
 (10.3.207.106) with Microsoft SMTP Server (TLS) id 14.16.227.3; Fri, 21 Feb
 2014 15:31:15 +0000
Received: from SERVER.bpd.local ([fe80::50fe:d0bf:d57d:2f5d]) by
 SERVER.bpd.local ([fe80::50fe:d0bf:d57d:2f5d%10]) with mapi; Fri, 21 Feb 2014
 08:31:13 -0700
Content-Type: multipart/mixed;
        boundary="_000_0D7E2AB4DAB13448A100F4A967F15C29010F798434DASERVERbpdlo_"
From:___________
To: _____________
Date: Fri, 21 Feb 2014 08:31:10 -0700
Subject: __________________________
Thread-Topic: _____________________________
Thread-Index: Ac8toIauLfTa3ulLRaCz4ClaFcUdMgArks5QAAS1bmAALg/IMA==
Message-ID: <0D7E2AB4DAB13448A100F4A967F15C29010F798434DA@SERVER.bpd.local>
Accept-Language: en-US
Content-Language: en-US
X-MS-Has-Attach: yes
X-MS-TNEF-Correlator: <0D7E2AB4DAB13448A100F4A967F15C29010F798434DA@SERVER.bpd.local>
acceptlanguage: en-US
MIME-Version: 1.0
X-MS-Exchange-Organization-OriginalArrivalTime: 21 Feb 2014 15:31:15.9707
 (UTC)
X-MS-Exchange-Organization-OriginalClientIPAddress: 69.146.164.109
X-MS-Exchange-Organization-OriginalServerIPAddress: 10.3.207.106
X-MS-Exchange-Organization-AuthSource: AM1EHSMHS006.ehs.local
X-MS-Exchange-Organization-AuthAs: Anonymous
X-MS-Exchange-Organization-MessageDirectionality: Incoming
X-MS-Exchange-Organization-ConnectorInfo: Dn%*$RO%0$FUIP%$LKIP%$KIPT%0$Id%0$Di%0$Tls%0$SF%0$PF%0$CF%0$FQDN%$TlsDn%$IpfH%IPV:NLI$EnfH%H:mail.bearpaw.org;RD:mail.bearpaw.org;EFVD:NLI$
X-MS-Exchange-Organization-Company-Id:
X-MS-Exchange-Organization-Attributed-Sender-Id:
X-MS-Exchange-Organization-OriginalSize: 283945
X-MS-Exchange-Organization-MessageScope: 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000
X-MS-Exchange-Organization-HygienePolicy: Standard
X-MS-Exchange-Organization-MessageLatencyInProgress: LSRV=AM1EHSMHS006.ehs.local:TOTAL=2|SMR=2;2014-02-21T15:31:18.435Z
Return-Path: _____________________
X-OriginalArrivalTime: 21 Feb 2014 15:31:22.0430 (UTC) FILETIME=[F98A1DE0:01CF2F19]
```

Thank you very much for any help that anyone can provide!  I appreciate it greatly!

Ben

Comment: Are these actual emails that you've verified were sent, or is this just backscatter?  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backscatter_(email)

Comment: These are actual emails that were sent.  I removed the to/from out of them.  Some are also conversations.  Last week, they were having a email conversation, this week, the server is not letting them pass.